# swift setNavigationBarHidden causing odd animation when VC slides in

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

My app looks like this *NavCont* - *TableView* - *VC1*

What I want to do is to hide the navbar in **VC1** and I do so by using this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

It does hide the navbar which is right, but the animation is a little bit strange. My whole view kinda "jumps up" 5px in the process which looks odd.

(When the view slides is there is a gap between the container and the status bar)

I have tried to set the animation to false, and also tried to toggle on/off (adjust scrollview insets) but nothing works.

If I dont hide the navigation bar at all the slide in animation works fine, so its something when the navigation bar gets hidden.

My content is also set to hug the top bar (const 0)

Worth saying is that this "bug" only happens the first time I push to the VC. If I then go back to the prev VC and push again the slide in / hide navbar animation works fine

Comment: Are you re-creating the VC each time?

Comment: Please add sufficient details to reproduce the issue. Otherwise everyone will just be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the symptoms I suspect that you perform some views' frames adjustments in this VC at a point when the frames of those views are not final. Try moving whatever frame-adjusting things you are doing in `viewDidLoad()` to `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.